# If I install Homebrew on macOS, am I required to use Xcode as my IDE?

Tags: xcode, visual-studio-code, homebrew

I'm a new developer, learning to set up environments both local and cloud-based. For local, I already have installed Node and git and they are working. And I use Visual Studio Code for editing files, for terminal, also for managing git repo.

I've heard good things about Homebrew and I'd like to try it, but on its installation instructions, it lists the following among its macOS requirements: "Command Line Tools (CLT) for Xcode: xcode-select --install, developer.apple.com/downloads or Xcode 3"

Does this mean I would be required to use Xcode every time I interact with Homebrew? Nothing against Xcode but I'd be surprised if Homebrew can't be used just as easily with some other IDE like VSCode or Sublime text, etc.

Comment: Homebrew isn't "used with" any IDE at all. You are comparing apples with kangaroos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need are the Xcode command line tools and not the IDE itself, they can be downloaded separately so you don’t have to install the full Xcode app.

So while Homebrew does make use of those command line tools it isn’t something you will notice when using homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew will use parts of Xcode, depends on some of Xcode. But you do not need to use Xcode as an IDE. Xcode also includes compiler, Command line Tools run from the Mac terminal, and it is those (Xcode)tools Homebrew depends on.
The full Xcode is huge.
Homebrew positions itself as the package manager missing from MacOS - it relies on parts of Xcode to run. There's no relationship with the Xcode IDE.